# java net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and showing blank page for any URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am new to Java, seems like there is something wrong in my Servlet as I am keep getting `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in the chrome browser and I am showing blank page for any URL I enter in the browser.

**Below is the code:**

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
  <display-name>My Application</display-name>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <name>mysessionid</name>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**HomeServlet.xml**

```
@WebServlet("/")
public final class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private HttpSession session = null;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

        session = request.getSession(false);
        System.out.println("session::: "+ session);
        if(session != null && !session.isNew()) {
            System.out.println("inside session only!");
            response.sendRedirect("index.html");
        } else {
            something(request, response);

        }


    }



    private String something(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    if(accessToken != null) {
        session = request.getSession();
        response.sendRedirect("index.html");
    }


}
```

Please tell me what went wrong above.

Comment: Can you debug it? I assume every time you are redirecting to 'index.html' request is again handled by your servlet and you are redirecting again to 'index.html', so it is redirection loop.

Comment: Can anyone please try look into this?

Comment: Please someone help me out on above issue..